# node installed but npm is not installed

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-package

## Problem

node -v  is working but, 
npm -v is not working, error

---

## Error encountered

```js
C:\Users\HackerGprat>node -v
v19.2.0

C:\Users\HackerGprat>npm -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\HackerGprat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\HackerGprat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
←[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)←[39m
    at createEnginesValidation ←[90m(C:\Users\HackerGprat\←[39mAppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\cli.js:7:15←[90m)←[39m
    at module.exports ←[90m(C:\Users\HackerGprat\←[39mAppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\cli.js:73:27←[90m)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> ←[90m(C:\Users\HackerGprat\←[39mAppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\bin\npm-cli.js:2:25←[90m)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\HackerGprat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\HackerGprat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}

Node.js v19.2.0
```

---

## Try : 1

### walkthrough installation

[image: installed]
[image]

my doubt is i did not checked ☑ the options of **automatic install necessary tools** becuase it will take lots of mb so i skiped it.. and by default it was unchecked too [ ]

**it did not working**, and given me error,

---

## Try : 2

### it's working on sandbox but not in real pc.

[image]

---

## Try : 3

tried to copy all installation folder from sandbox to real pc,

- node -v -> working
- npm -v -> **not working**, **error**

---

## Try : 4

### Trying without installing node, copied from sandbox

- node -v -> working
- npm -v -> **not working, error**

[image]

---

## Try : 5

### Tried to change the location with new name **NJS**

- node -v -> working
- npm -v -> **not working, error**

[image]

Comment: Npm and node is not the same. You might have not installed npm. Try reinstall it.

Comment: did it 3 time. 
1st time not installed.. 
2nd time i thought i did somthing wrong.. 
3rd installtions for the stack overflow .. 

in 4th installtion i will check the "automatic install all necessary tools" but i'm not 100% sure it will fix it or not..

Comment: Maybe you want to try installing it via [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) instead.

Comment: Remember to remove all npm and node install before that

Comment: try installing node 16 or 14

Comment: i tried same error in every version, maybe there is issue with pc. because its working on sandbox,  see i updated problem @dantedx

Answer (score 0):

## Try 6 : Successfully Installed npm

as you can see the last line

```
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\HackerGprat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\HackerGprat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
```

its pointing to `AppData` folder, 
and saying there is `npm` folder

just `delete` that `npm folder` and reinstall the node

and see it started again working..

### results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on my mac machine, I solved it by running the following commands:

```
brew cleanup
```

```
brew uninstall node
```

```
brew install node
```

after running these 3 commands, `node` and `npm` both got installed:

```
$ node -v
v21.6.2

$ npm -v
10.2.4
```