# Cannot run any npm commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

At first I was getting the following error message on running **npm run start** inside my project directory.

> ```
> npm err! code enoent 
> npm err! syscall spawn bash 
> npm err! 
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\naray\OneDrive\Desktop\Ananth\Courses\udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2022\complete-node-bootcamp-master\4-natours\starter-main
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\naray\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-03T10_29_53_655Z-debug-0.log
> ```

Then I ran **npm install -g npm** and now I cannot run any npm command. I keep getting the same error message (as shown below) for all npm commands.

> ```
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946
> const err = new Error(message);
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
> Require stack:
>
> C:\\Users\\naray\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js
> C:\\Users\\naray\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js
> at Module.\_resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
> at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at createEnginesValidation (C:\\Users\\naray\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js:7:15)
> at module.exports (C:\\Users\\naray\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js:78:27)  
> at Object.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Users\\naray\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js:2:25)
> at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
> at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32) {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: \[
>   'C:\\Users\\naray\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
>   'C:\\Users\\naray\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
>   \]
>   }
> ```

I even tried running **npm cache clean --force** but got the same message.

Can anyone please help me resolve this?

Comment: Check that you have a valid `package.json` file inside your project folder. Otherwise run `npm init`.

Comment: I have a package.json file and running any npm command gives me the same error

Comment: This looks very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74792920/node-installed-but-npm-is-not-installed

Comment: Try reinstalling Node.js

Comment: @IVOGELOV reinstalling didn't work

Comment: Check that `c:\users\naray\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\package.json` exists.

Comment: ensure that you are in the good folder.